# After loading an animated gif, I want it to change to a jpg

Tags: javascript, jquery, gif

I am using frames, and would like the page to load using animated gifs, but once loaded, I want the links to be jpegs with rollovers. Is it possible to have the final image a jpg loaded after the animated gif?

Comment: Yes it's possible. What have you tried?

Comment: Remove the gif and add a jpeg?

Comment: Is it that you want the animations to stop after some time? If so, you can set the animated gifs to not loop.

Comment: I'm really confused as you what you want, you provided no examples of any kind. I provided my best answer below given that you want your gif to switch to a jpg on rollover. I'm sorry I had to downvote your question, it isn't nearly specific enough, you provided no examples, and no one here even knows what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Uh, I don't really get what you're doing, but you change the src of an image in jquery like this:

```
$('.myimageselector').attr('src', 'mynewimage.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying you would like to convert a gif to a jpg on the client side, then no.  You could always have something running server side sending them the files in the form of jpg (after being converted from gifs).

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this using the jQuery `.hover` function.

like this:

```
$('imageselector').hover(function(){
    $(this).attr('src','newimage.jpg');
},function(){
    $(this).attr('src','oldimage.gif');
});
```

Here is my example:

http://jsfiddle.net/MarkKramer/UEhFu/

Comment: Sorry for being so vague. I have a banner that animates. Once the animation is complete, I have text that fades in (gifs)... once the text fades in, I would like to change them to jpgs so that the text won't animate, and they'll be simple rollover images. Sorry for not being clear.. does the above make sense?

Comment: Kind of, but I can't visualize what it is that you want,provide what you said in your question and include an example of what you mean so we know exactly what it is you want.